# Install masonry in isotope items (not masonry layout of isotope!)

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I have isotope grid installed with filters, and it works fine :

```
    var $grid = $('.grid')
    $grid.isotope({
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        itemSelector: '.box',
        stagger: 30, // item transitions 30ms after one another
        filter: '', // shown by default
        percentPosition: true,
        getSortData: {
            number: '.number parseInt'
        }
    });
```

In my isotope grid items (.box) I would like my contents organized as a masonry grid. I tried first to install masonry after isotope, it did not work. Firefox says: "Error in parsing value for ‘top’.  Declaration dropped. index.html:1:1". And also the same with 'left'.:

```
    $('.box').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.div',
        columnWidth: '.div-sizer',
        percentPosition: true
    })
```

I also asked the free GPT chat what is the problem, it suggested these codes, but Firefox says the same as at above codes:

```
    // Initialize Masonry on Isotope's items
    $grid.find('.box').each(function() {
        var masonry = new Masonry(this, {
            itemSelector: '.div',
            columnWidth: '.div-sizer',
            percentPosition: true
            // Additional Masonry options...
        });
    });
```

My CSS for isotope and masonry elements :

```
/* isotope* grid and item */
.grid {display:block;width:calc(90% + 80px);margin:50px auto;} 
.box {width:100%;margin:0 0 20px 0 !important;padding:3%;background:#f7f7f7;font-size:initial;}
/* masonry items */
.div {width:25%;float:left;padding:20px;}
.div-sizer {width:25%}
.div1 {width:100%;}
.div2 {width:50%;}
```

First of all, I do not understand what is the problem of Firefox, it does not indicate any css line where the problem is with top and left, my html first line is as always : `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Second problem is that the contents in my grid items do not be ordered like masonry.